# Search for a particular element in BlockingCollection

Tags: c#, multithreading, blockingcollection

I have a `BlockingCollection`:

```
private readonly BlockingCollection<ImageKeys> myCompletedImages;
```

I have a method that adds items to the `BlockingCollection`:

```
public void addItem(ImageKey theImagekey)
{
    if (this.myCompletedImages.Contains(theImagekey)) // Here it says
                                                      // I do not have "Contains"
    {         
        return;
    }
    this.myCompletedImages.Add(theImagekey);
}
```

How to know if a particular element is present in a `BlockingCollection`? Since `Contains` is not present.. Is there any other way I can do it?

Comment: Even if you could, such a method would be useless as it could be added after you check if  it exists and before you add the item itself.

Comment: There is an extension method `Contains<>` in System.Linq and you can even provide a `IEqualityComparer<T>`

Comment: @Hazrelle as Servy already explained that would be useless, because a matching item may be added between the check and the `Add` call

Comment: @Mr.Curious what are you trying to do? Why are you using a BlockingCollection instead of eg `ConcurrentDictionary`? There are probably better ways (and better collections) for doing whatever you want to do. Are you trying to prevent posting duplicate messages to a subscriber/worker perhaps?

Comment: Use a thread safe queue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Searching a `BlockingCollection<T>` to see if it contains a particular element, is a functionality not needed for the intended usage of this class, which is to facilitate producer-consumer scenarios. So this class does not expose a `Contains` method as part of its public API. You *could* exploit the fact that the class implements the `IEnumerable<T>` interface, and use the LINQ [`Contains`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.contains) operator, however keep in mind [this cautionary note](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.concurrent.concurrentbag-1#thread-safety) from the `ConcurrentBag<T>` class. AFAIK it applies to all concurrent collections in general:

> All public and protected members of `ConcurrentBag<T>` are thread-safe and may be used concurrently from multiple threads. However, members accessed through one of the interfaces the `ConcurrentBag<T>` implements, **including extension methods**, are not guaranteed to be thread safe, and may need to be synchronized by the caller.

(emphasis added)

So you could safely use the LINQ `Contains` extension method only after the "battle" is over, and all the concurrent operations on the `BlockingCollection<T>` instance have ended. Which is probably not what you want. In which case the `BlockingCollection<T>` is probably not the right tool for whatever problem you are trying to solve.